# can any one tell me which is the best way to learn spring

Tags: java, spring

can any one tell me the best way to learn spring.

i have sound work experience in struts. and little experience in jsp and hibernate

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use it!

Write a simple app using Spring (use the standard docs) and then go back and rewrite it. Write lots of code.

Spring Recipes is also a good book.

Comment: I second the Spring Recipes book.  Way way better than Spring In Action IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I found [Spring in Action](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Spring-Action-Craig-Walls/dp/1933988134/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1243325673&sr=8-1) to be an excellent guide

Answer (score 2):

Start reading Martin Fowler's [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) and then start reading [Spring's doc](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/index.html) (I've found the doc is one of the best books).

Of course following some tutorials on internet will help but I've found reading first the basics is the best for understanding the framework

Comment: I second victor here, the docs are sufficient enough. +1

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend you to go through the spring documents. You can also explore [Spring MVC fast Tutorial](http://maestric.com/en/doc/java/spring)
Anyway, if you are a pro to other frameworks, you can also go through this tutorial to have hands on http ://raibledesigns.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=SpringControllers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about how relevent it is anymore since Rod Johnson and the EJB3 crew have joined forces and seem to be heading in the same direction together.
EJB3 now offers dependency injection using annotations rather than yet another XML configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

the distribution should include a project called the petstore clinic.  This will give you a very good overview on how to use latest techniques with full spring stack.

Answer (score -2):

A book will be helpful.

Well, I have the habit of learning from Internet.

Eg: [The Complete Spring Tutorial - http://www.roseindia.net/spring/index.shtml](http://www.roseindia.net/spring/index.shtml)

Comment: -1 from me - I would not recommend Rose India for anything.

Comment: Of course it is.  Just telling you why I voted you down.  For anyone who's following along, I think the quality is poor.  It's not a source I'd recommend to anyone who's serious about learning a topic.